# How to serialize only some of class variables?

Tags: java, serialization

Is there any possibility to choose some of class variables, which I want to serialize ?

Following simple example (Just to demonstrate the way I want to use serialization):
I have a database of all users, each time I start my app I get a screen containing all users.
It's not critical important to have the most recent list of all users. For better performance I save the returned list of users(from database) to a local .dat file, at next app start the users are loaded from .dat file. The .dat file is refreshed each N minutes or on users demand...
Because of security I don't want to save passwords to a local .dat file, it's enough to save just username, email, friends.
How it's possible to achieve this, do I need to create a separate UserWithoutPassword class, or is there any possibility to choose variables for serialization?

```java
@Entity
class User implements Serializable {
    String username;
    String email;
    String password;
    List<User> friends;

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just declare some fields as `transient`:

```
transient int doNotSerialize;
```

And they will not be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to declare a [`serialPersistentFields` member](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#6250) and populate it with the field names you want to serialize.